# Making wildcard nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, nopcommerce

First of all I want to ask is what I have to do to make a website that support wildcard like you receive request as blog.domainname.com and forum.domainname.com. It is server setting that I have to do or I have to make application like that to support wildcard. Like I want to nopcommerce to support wildcard ?

Thanks in advace..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind multiple website in IIS to the same IP / port and distinguish them by host header.

When you define bindings in IIS specify same IP / port and add blog.domainname.com as host header for your blog website and forum.domainname.com to your forum.

Comment: so it is doesn't depend on Website? It's just IIS setting.??

Comment: Yes, it's just IIS configuration. Doesn't require any code changes in the web site.

Comment: Do you have any good link to achieve this.? It will really helpful..thanks

Comment: Thanks but this article tells how to do it on windows 2000. I need something to do it on windows 2008 R2..

Comment: Thanks found for IIS 7. In IIS 7 you have edit binding option and there you can add host name.

Comment: I have edited binding for my default website and added two host name like blog.domainname.com and company.domainname.com. But I tried to browse them but Page Could find error was displayed. So Do I have to register the domains? Can I register multiple domain for one ip address? [Note:] I have dedicated server

Comment: Yes, you need to add DNS A records for each subdomain and point them to the same IP of your dedicated server.